# Usage du passé simple dans les textes

Tags: usage, temps-grammatical

Lors des cours de français, les profs nous disaient que le passé simple est normalement utilisé dans le cadre de la littérature (romans, poèmes, etc.). Pourtant, je le croise parfois dans un contexte hors littérature comme un rapport de thèse scientifique, où il est employé côte à côte avec le passé composé.

Ma question est : peut-on employer le passé simple au lieu du passé composé dans n'importe quelle situation pour la rendre plus jolie ou bien y a-t-il une règle ?

Comment: En vertu de la concordance des temps, on n'emploie normalement pas le passé simple avec le passé composé. Aurais-tu des exemples ?

Comment: Par côte à côte je ne veux pas dire dans la même phrase mais dans le même chapitre, l'introduction par exemple. Par exemple, dans l'article que je consulte, il y a une phrase 'les expériences **montrèrent** pourtant que....' suivie par une autre 'Lason et. Al. **ont démontré**que' . La question c'est que quelle est la règle d'usage de passé simple dans un contexte hors littérature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pour commencer, on ne peut pas mélanger passé composé et passé simple, à part pour un effet de style dans certains cas spécifiques, par exemple un passage du texte qui serait un rappel historique, ou en tout cas un récit séparé ("en 1765, Lavoisier montra que... et par nos travaux, nous avons montré que..."). Mais mis à part ce genre d'effet de style, la règle est : on choisit l'un des deux comme temps du récit et on s'y tient.

Quant à savoir quel temps du récit choisir : **le passé simple est quasi universel dans la littérature, les textes sur l'Histoire utilisent très souvent le présent de narration, et dans les autres contextes on préfère le passé composé**. Ce ne sont pas des règles strictes, plutôt des conventions, mais s'en écarter attirera l'attention et paraîtra souvent assez maladroit. On trouve quelques romans au présent ou au passé composé, mais les écarts sont plus rares dans les contextes qui se prêtent moins aux effets de style. Pour un rapport de thèse par exemple, le passé simple n'est pas approprié.

Comment: Il me semble que les thèses (à la fois suffisament formelles et en même temps liées au présent) tout comme le vieux style journalistique sont justement le genre de cas où il y a une raison de distinguer la valeur du passé simple (un fait passé) de celle du passé composé (quelque chose déjà accompli au moment présent). Cette distinction n'est évidement plus courante de nos jours, mais il me semble que la question elle-même est bien plus éclairée que cette réponse. Je reste sur ma faim.